# Javascript Interface for BrowserComponent like in Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, codenameone

I am trying to implement a simple editing feature in a BrowserComponent of a Codename One Java app.

```
BrowserComponent editText=new BrowserComponent();

editText.addJSCallback(
    "call= function(result){callback.onSuccess(result);}",
    res -> {
        System.out.println(res);

    }
);

editText.execute("body=document.body;body.innerHTML='<div id=\"editText\" style=\"font-size:40px;\";contenteditable=\"true\">This text can be edited by the user.</div>';");


    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            editText.execute("var position = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;call(position);");
        }
    });
```

Another version:

```
editText.addWebEventListener("onload",(e)->{
        System.out.println("onload");

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        editText.addJSCallback(
                "var position = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;callback.onSuccess(position);",
                res -> {
                    System.out.println(res);

                }
        );
    }

});

            
        }
    );

    editText.setPage("<HTML><BODY><div id=\"editText\" style=\"font-size:40px;\" contenteditable=\"true\">This text can be edited by the user.</div></BODY></HTML>","");
    mainLayout.add(editText);
```

I do not know if this is what could be like the Javascript interface in Android for the WebView (I am porting that Android app).

Indeed nothing happens when the user clicks the button.
I think it's the Java callback side that does not work, because if the user does not enter the text field at all (selection is not available) I get:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: IndexSizeError: The index is not in the allowed range.
```

after clicking the button.

In the second version the onload event is not called at all.

What's wrong? How to achieve the same fuctionality of Javascript Interface in Android?

Comment: I don't use interop much but a couple of things stand out. First you need to use the onLoad callback for writing code that expects the content to be there. Second your assumption that you can execute on a blank page seem to be wrong. You need to load a page. You can provide hardcoded HTML/JavaScript using `setPage() ` and then work on that after the onLoad which seems to be what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @Shai Almog Notice that execute("el=document.getElementById('editText');el.innerHTML='changed';"); (in the listener) works, so I do not think the page is not well-formed inside the BrowserComponent. I do not need just one-shot call, every click has to be sort of an "event" inside the backing Java code, like in Android. Why that callback is not working? How to have the same like on Android? Or similar workaround?

Comment: You can have these things just like in Android you only need to start binding them after the "onLoad" callback occurred to make sure the browser component is ready for you. You can then write whatever you want at that point. Think of it this way, you're in the Codename One thread. When you do new `BrowserComonent` it doesn't exist. It needs to create the browser in the OS native thread and even then the browser has its own thread which it needs to initialize and load. That can happen ages later... So first usage must start when we know the browser is ready for your code.

Comment: @Shai Almog So, I put some instructions in the onload callback, but the main fact here is that it seems that the callbacks are separate from each other, that is, if I define a function in one callback and then I want to call it in another I get runtime exception "Can't find variable: call". I need a way to call Java code from JS script that's in the HTML page, like on Android. I do not know how.

Comment: @Shai Almog I call addWebEventListener to set a callback for the "onload" event that sets another callback inside the button event, then (outside of the onload stuff) I call setPage as next instruction, the page is loaded but the event never gets called.

Comment: If you call setPage after onLoad then this will discard your JS. Can you edit the question to show what you tried?

Comment: @Shai Almog setPage is called first, the addWebEventListener is written above it but does not call the onload event, it just sets the callback. Still that event is not called, I put a simple println to check. In the addWebEventListener callback I put some additional callback assignment so to be sure it binds in a fully loaded JS environment as you said, but the execution does not even reach that point.

Comment: onLoad MUST be invoked. If it isn't invoked then something is seriously wrong. Can you edit the post with your revised code?

Comment: @Shai Almog I improved the question with the new code. Thanks

Comment: Notice the event name is "onLoad" not "onload".  You can use the BrowserComponent.onLoad constant to ensure this.

Comment: @steve hannah Thanks, you are right. Now it works.